# Existence of a probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be countable. Further let $(A_1, A_2, ...)$ be a  (possibly finite) partition of $\Omega$ and $\mathbb P_j$ a probability measure on $(A_j, \mathcal P(A_j))$ for all $j$.

How can I show that there is a probability measure $\mathbb P$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal P(\Omega))$ where $\mathbb P(A_j) > 0$ and $\mathbb P( \cdot | A_j)= \mathbb P_j$ for all $j$?

Some help would be much appreciated, haven't done anything with measures in a while.

Comment: Hint: Law of total probability.

Comment: Ok I know what the law says but have no idea how to make use of it in terms of the given problem. Can you show me some approach please?

Comment: Set *by definition* $\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_j \mathbb P_j(A\cap A_j) p_j$, where $p_j>0$ are some positive numbers with $\sum_j p_j = 1$. Show that this $\mathbb P$ has the desired properties.